# On which language does WPF applications are developed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, programming-languages

do we need to learn a new programming language if we want to use WPF. like for Winforms we use C#.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WPF is a .NET framework. Any .NET language will suffice. If you already know C#, then use that.

Others, that spring to mind:

- VB.NET
- C++.NET
- IronPython / IronRuby

Also, you will probably want to learn some [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language), since that is often used as markup for WPF, leading to a more web development style.

Comment: F#, C#, Visual C++ is not meant to work fluenty with WPF. As you said any .Net language, but C# and VB.Net have the best support.

Comment: Having recently switched from Delphi, I can say that learning XAML is far more useful, but more difficult, than C#/VB.  A lot of the work is done in XAML, and even things that can also be done in C#/VB are usually better done in XAML.  Also, it seems to be easier to find support and examples in C# than VB.

Comment: @coldandtired so true. I kinda like to think of WPF as some new kind of html . The xaml really seems like html where you can take(bind) logic and variables away from the code. UI and logic separation has always been better with web technologies (asp.net mvc, ROR) so WPF seems like the same flavor on windows. Wonder if anyone else agrees with me.

Comment: @giddy, yep, I agree. WPF is Web development for the desktop. It is neat, but slows down my IDE a *lot*...

Comment: yea seriously, my dev machine happens to be a 3y/o laptop so you can imagine! I'm so tempted to buy a new one and will hook it upto to a new monitor!

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Darren answer. Yes you can write the code in C# but learn **XAML**. Don't be fooled into thinking XAML is magic automatically created by the designer when you design your UI.

WPF is different from windows forms in the sense of trying to achieve separation between UI and Logic. So make sure you learn enough about data-binding with XAML.

See this article : [Moving toward WPF one step at a Time.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MovingTowardWpfBinding.aspx)

(This is out of a personal mistake I made and ended up writing the most horrific piece of Silverlight code.. hacking it together as if it was windows forms with code behind in each usercontrol.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# to create your WPF application. More information can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx

Answer (score 1):

WPF is a new Display Technology that uses [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) to render everything(from `Button`, `Label` to graphics) that uses hardware acceleration and it's a dramatic shift from all the earlier technologies(WinForms,MFC,Visual Basic etc) which used [GDI/GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [User32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#User32.dll).

In order to use this new technology, only leaning c#(or any language that targets the CLR) is sufficient.However, having learned XAML makes creating WPF applications very easy.This is because the WPF API has been designed in such a way that most of the things can be done declaratively(Like animations etc).

So, learning XAML is not required but it is recommended.

Comment: I disagree. To really know/use/understand the WPF framework properly you really **need** to learn some XAML. Especially data-binding. Other you'll be using WPF to programming the windows forms way, which can turn messy.

Comment: I just wrote this to tell him that XAML and WPF can be seperately used, however using XAML makes WPF programming much easy.Still disagree?

Comment: Your first two paras were all good. I only disagree with the last line in your question. Learning XAML **IS** required. Without it you will write ugly, nasty code and not realize what WPF is all about and why its different. Using XAML in WPF doesn't make it easy... some xaml is necessary.. charles petzolds WPF book has 50% (and most other books) have a good solid portion of WPF dedicated to XAML only.

Comment: I just made a distiction between WPF and XAML and to solidify that I wrote that it is POSSIBLE to create a WPF application without using XAML. But just because a thing is possible does not mean that we have to do it. So I said that it is recommended to use XAML as it will make your life easier like what you said(no ugly, nasty code) **:)**

Comment: You mean Create a WPF app without using **XAML**! =P True, Yea I get what your saying =)

Comment: hahaha no giddy, i will never do/recommend that ;) i love xaml

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be best off learning XAML, which is a dialect of XML, but you can use your C# skills still.